# Getting a Professional Engineering License (or job in similar setting) without ABET degree

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I am looking for a job in engineering and finding many jobs in construction or consulting suggest/require ABET degrees. I followed a non-traditional route (B.A. in Spanish literature followed by M.S. in Mechanical Engineering). Since Master's degree's are not ABET accredited, I don't have an ABET degree even though I studied all of the same core classes (and a few extra for the Master's).

I feel like I made a terrible decision to get a Master's degree and not a second Bachelor's. Technically in Massachusetts I can still get a PE with [8 years experience](https://www.pcshq.com/?page=engineeringandrelatedfields,umassachusettspebycomityeligibilityrequi) (or maybe 12 depending on if my background fits classification C), but it is difficult for me to get on that track to begin with.

Does anyone know of a way to get my coursework certified, or perhaps firms that hire non-traditional backgrounds and offer training? Any other advice or suggestions? Should I just take the FE exam anyways?

Comment: Other suggestion: Many engineering jobs in the USA do not require PE. Every car, truck, missile, aircraft, computer, and whatever is engineered without being signed off by a PE.

Comment: That is a possibility. I'm working at a material science startup right now and could just stay in the fields that you mentioned. However, I feel like I'm missing out on a huge market - and a career working on projects such as buildings, bridges, or other structures might be very satisfying for me. I just want to know if it's possible for someone with my background.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because guessing how certain qualifications could be or will be certified is not part of this SE.

Answer (score 1):

#### Most people define engineers by their undergraduate degree.

PE Boards seem to agree and want an undergraduate degree for professional engineers.  Graduate work just isn't the same.  I suppose you could search all the state boards and see if any accept master's degrees, but your main problem will be getting a job in engineering consulting anyway.

Is there someone out there who could hire you?  Sure, but finding them will be your problem.  You won't get past the automated resume screen with a Liberal Arts undergrad.

You comment on the question states you want to do structural design.  Everyone doing this work is a Civil or maybe a Mechanical who has been at a civil firm.  I just don't think you have the background to compete with the BSCE who also has a master's in structural design.  I think you should adjust your career goals.  You will need to cast a wide net to get into the profession, and then you can try to move to consulting.

Comment: To add to this, I'm somewhat bemused as to how it possible to get a Masters of Science without first attaining a Bachelor of Science. From my experience BS (or B Eng) leads to MS (or M Eng) which leads to PhD which then leads to Doctorate of Science (or Engineering). Similarly BA leads to MA ... One streams deals with the Science (or Science & Technology ) stream the other with the Arts stream. One doesn't mix & match to produce a hybrid. It's almost like trying to make a family from disparate orphans.

Comment: @Fred, there are liberal arts schools out there who don't offer engineering degrees that actually promote this bad idea.  A good MS school would've set better expectations.